# Check my answer - Differential of $P(A)=\det(A^{-1}-A)$

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

We are asked to find the differential of $P: GL_n(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$, $P(A)=\det(A^{-1}-A)$

and show it is differentiable.

If we define $f(A)=\det(A)$ and $g(A)=A^{-1}-A$ then it is clear that $P(A)=f(g(A))$ and so with chain rule:

$$P'(A)=f'(g(A))g'(A)$$

$f'(A)=\operatorname{trace}(\operatorname{adj}(A)D_A)$ where $D_A$ is the differential of A, and so $f'(A^{-1}-A)=\operatorname{trace}(\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1}-A) D_{A^{-1}-A})$

$g'(A)=D_{A^{-1}-A}$

and so

$$P'(A) =\operatorname{trace}(\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1}-A) D_{A^{-1}-A})*D_{A^{-1}-A}$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the map $A \mapsto A^{-1}$ is smooth, and $\det$ is smooth, it follows that $P$ is differentiable everywhere that $A$ is invertible.

I find the notation in the question a little hard to follow. Here is an alternative, which may help:

If we let $f(A) = \det A$, then if $A$ is invertible we can write $Df(A)(\Delta) = \det A \operatorname{tr} (A^{-1} \Delta)$. Since $(\det A  )A^{-1} = \operatorname{adj} A$, we can write
$Df(A)(\Delta) = \operatorname{tr} (\operatorname{adj}(A) \Delta)$ and using a continuity argument establishes the result for all $A$.

If $g(A) = A^{-1} -A$, then $Dg(A)(\Delta) = -(A^{-1} \Delta A^{-1} + \Delta)$.

Then $Df \circ g (A) (\Delta) = Df(g(A)) (Dg(A)(\Delta))$.

Hence
\begin{eqnarray}
DP(A)(\Delta) &=& \operatorname{tr}(\operatorname{adj}(g(A)) (Dg(A)(\Delta))) \\
&=&
\operatorname{tr}(\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1}-A) (-(A^{-1} \Delta A^{-1} + \Delta)) ) \\
&=& - \operatorname{tr}(\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1}-A) (A^{-1} \Delta A^{-1} + \Delta) )
\end{eqnarray}

**Addendum**: Differentiating $g$:

We can write $g(A) = g_1(A)+g_2(A)$, with $g_1(A) = A^{-1}, g_2(A) = -A$.

It is clear that $D g_2(A)(\Delta) = -\Delta$.

For $g_1$, it is easiest to compute the derivative from first principles. Assuming that $\|\Delta\| < {1 \over 2\|A^{-1}\|}$, we have
$g_1(A+\Delta) = (A+\Delta)^{-1} = ((I+\Delta)A)^{-1} = A^{-1} (I+\Delta A^{-1})^{-1} = A^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k (\Delta A^{-1})^k$, that is,
$g_1(A+\Delta) = g_1(A) -A^{-1} \Delta A^{-1} + \sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^k (\Delta A^{-1})^k$. We have $\|\sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^k (\Delta A^{-1})^k \| \le \|\Delta\|^2 \|A^{-1}\|^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty (\|\Delta\| \|A^{-1}\|)^2 \le 2 \|\Delta\|^2 \|A^{-1}\|^2$ (in particular, it is $o(\|\Delta\|)$), hence
$D g_1(A)( \Delta) = -A^{-1} \Delta A^{-1}$.

Comment: could you explain how you derived g?

Comment: I added a note.